# comparing and Copying an content of a array into another array by adding a new object into an existing array using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, for-loop

I have two arrays containing two objects in it 
vm.baselinesData=[Object,Object] again further the two objects contains again two objects each inside it 0:Object 1:Object further the each object have property as different "ServiceName"(a variable) and another property as baselines[image: the image of array follows as this]

I have a another array  vm.contractYearData having a same structure of array and properties.

```
 for(var i=0;i < vm.baselinesData.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j< vm.contractYearData.length;j++){
      if(vm.baselinesData[i].serviceName == vm.contractYearData[j].serviceName){
          vm.baselinesData[i].yearBaselines = vm.contractYearData[j].baselines;
      }
  }
}
```

How can i add a new object called yearBaselines into an each object of vm.baselinesData array by comparing the service name of each object of this array with that of vm.contractYearData

Answer (score 0):

My code above answers this question with the change in loop flow